# PHP - Removing specific words from sentence

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract a location from common phrases about the weather using PHP. My current approach is using `str_replace()`, but it is having some unintended results. Parts of zip codes are being replaced because `str_replace()` is replacing part of the zip code while searching for "10 day" or "7 day" forecast

```
$weather_location_1 = "10 day forecast for 90210";
$weather_location_2 = "weather near seattle, wa";
$weather_location_3 = "temperature 78665";

function get_weather_location($weather_location){
    $weatherwords = array("weather", "forecast", "temperature", "near", "for", "10", "ten", "7", "seven", "day");
    $weather_location= str_replace($weatherwords, "", $weather_location);
    $weather_location= trim($weather_location);
    return $weather_location;
}

$weather_location_1 = get_weather_location($weather_location_1);
echo $weather_location_1; // returns "902", but I want it to return 90210

$weather_location_2 = get_weather_location($weather_location_2);
echo $weather_location_2; // returns "seattle, wa", works as intended

$weather_location_3 = get_weather_location($weather_location_3);
echo $weather_location_3; // returns "8665", but I want it to return 78665
```

What should I use instead of `str_replace()` so that parts of the zip code aren't replaced, only each complete word in the `$weatherwords` array, and not "10" or "7" from zipcodes? Instead of `str_replace()`, I'm looking for `word_replace()` or something that just replaces each word in `$weatherwords`, not all matching substrings.

Comment: Use `preg_replace()` with a regular expression that matches word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks Barmar!!! You're always the first one. You answered my question yesterday :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace) instead of [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace), using a regex that asserts a word boundary on either side of the words you want to remove. This will prevent it removing `10` in `90210` or `7` in `78665`.

```
function get_weather_location($weather_location){
    $weatherwords = array("weather", "forecast", "temperature", "near", "for", "10", "ten", "7", "seven", "day");
    $weather_regex = '/\b(' . implode('|', $weatherwords) . ')\b/';
    $weather_location= preg_replace($weather_regex, "", $weather_location);
    $weather_location= trim($weather_location);
    return $weather_location;
}
```

Output:

```
90210
seattle, wa
78665
```

Answer (score 0):

FIRST OF ALL you will have to find patterns.

What I mean:

Please think about a pattern which you could tell your 7 year old daughter to convert or extract the desired data.

All she knows is this pattern and the original data. Like a printed newspaper and some basic rules.

She does not know what "weather" or a forecast is but she can read words. A computer is much less intelligent as a 7 year old child. ;-)

What you are currently doing is not helpful.
If you replace 7 in ZIP codes  with nothing codes you will end in HELL.  That's no usable pattern.

Maybe you will only a few or 100'rds of different patterns  like  "Z(Z) day forecast for XXXXXXX";    where X is between  ? and ?

"weather near XXXXXX, ZZ"  would also be a human and computer understandable pattern.

If you have defined all these patterns then you can convert them to regexps and check if they will convert the real life data correctly.

The topic regexps is rather complex with a number of books written on it. So nothing for an answer like this.

Comment: Although I like your attempt to describe with your own words what a regex is and how to try to construct it, you don't give a single example based on OP's question nor point him to the correct function (i.e. `preg_replace`) to use in php. Have a look at @Nick's answer which does all of the above in less lines.

Comment: @Zeitounator  I saw and see the problem on a meta level .. preg_replace does not help if you cant' identify the underlying patterns and have no knowledge about regexps.  The examples from the OP are only a very few examples from bazillions of possibilities.  But as the Op accepted the answer of Nick this discussion here is without value. Usually I post working code examples  instead of commenting "use XY " but here  i felt that the problem is somewhere else. and not to be fixed by a 4 liner.